# is it possible to use different core library version for testing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, open-source

I love OSS contribution but trying to get involved into OSS contribution. Recent I give a try to rails 4.2.4.rc1 with rails 4.2.3 and got failure for testcases.

The app works perfectly with rails4.2.3 and in the latest release candidate it's throwing some errors. I'm trying to figure out the issue.

could anyone help me to find the change from 4.2.3 version to 4.2.4.rc1 in main rails repository? I feel that will help me to resolve the bug.

How I can find the difference from github.

Note: changeLog only contains the error message not the commit details.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? You have an app that works fine with 4.2.3 and have a 4.2.4.rc1 checkout with local changes? Which tests fail? Also, I do not see exactly how your question title fits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I grasp your question.
You are speaking about tests *from rails* but also about an app that works.

If you want to try different rails versions for your app, I would use rvm and gemsets. [Official documentation](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics), but you will find imho nicer tutorials about that elsewehere. Actually, I would *always* use rvm and gemsets :) .

Changes between two versions can be seen on the github webpages, e.g. for [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare) - coming from the small green two-arrow-button to create pull-requests. Or you do it on the commandline `git help diff`, plus there are various graphical tools which I rarely resort to use (I am happy with `gitk` but there are probably fancier alternatives).